# JRoute giving wrong path for new menu items

Tags: php, joomla

Since a recent point in time (I believe since I installed the paid version of HikaShop) JRoute gives the wrong SEF url for all new menu items and 404 errors.

For example `JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=<OLD MENU ITEMID>')` returns the correct url path `/<MENU ITEM ALIAS>` (and results in NO 404 errors)...

... but `JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=<NEW MENU ITEMID>')` returns the wrong url path `/Products/<MENU ITEM ALIAS` (and results in 404 errors)

The behaviour can be seen for all new menu items whether or not using the HikaShop component - so it may be nothing to do with HikaShop.

I have checked the output of router.php for HikaShop and it appears to be working okay

I would like to debug JRoute further but in Joomla 3.5 cannot find where this class is defined. Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 APIs refer to methods.php, but I cannot find this file for 3.5 API

So at a loss as to how to proceed... Until I get this sorted the site is unusable...

Comment: Further information: I have checked the Joomla database (table _menu) which shows the addition of `/Products/` to the 'path' while the 'alias' is okay. So it seems that the problem arises at the time of creating the menu item. This behaviour is seen in all menu items after the installation of HikaShop that creates its own menu items in the Joomla table.

Comment: Further information: checking the $table data in the `save` function `/administrator/components/com_menus/models/item.php` at the time a new menu item is saved, the menu item name, alias and path all appear to be correct, however when I manually override the alias to `ProductsXX` for the HikaShop menu item linking to `index.php?option=com_hikashop&ctrl=product` (HikaShop had set this to `Products` on installation), then I get `/ProductsXX/` in the path for any new menu items created - so it does appear to relate to a HikaShop problem

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a Joomla problem, which has long history: [new menu item - wrong address](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=624&t=715809). After rebuilding the menu items the issue with `/Products/` in the path was resolved.